# C# - GetValue - Object Does Not Match Target Type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to write a generic method to compare two objects (I purposefully have two different types coming in. The second one has the same properties as the first one. The first just has more.).

I want to make sure the properties have the same values. The following code works for most of the properties that I have in the objects, but occasionally it throws the:

> "Object Does Not Match Target Type"

...error at

`var valFirst = prop.GetValue(manuallyCreated, null) as IComparable;`

```
public static bool SameCompare<T, T2>(T manuallyCreated, T2 generated){
var propertiesForGenerated = generated.GetType().GetProperties();
int compareValue = 0;

foreach (var prop in propertiesForGenerated) {

    var valFirst = prop.GetValue(manuallyCreated, null) as IComparable;
    var valSecond = prop.GetValue(generated, null) as IComparable;
    if (valFirst == null && valSecond == null)
        continue;
    else if (valFirst == null) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(prop + "s are not equal");
        return false;
    }
    else if (valSecond == null) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(prop + "s are not equal");
        return false;
    }
    else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(System.DateTime)) {
        TimeSpan timeDiff = (DateTime)valFirst - (DateTime)valSecond;
        if (timeDiff.Seconds != 0) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(prop + "s are not equal");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        compareValue = valFirst.CompareTo(valSecond);
    if (compareValue != 0) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(prop + "s are not equal");
        return false;
    }
}

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("All values are equal");
return true;
}
```

Comment: What is the case when it throws?

Comment: When I am checking a value called Procedure. The type is long and value is 845

Comment: This code could only work completely troublefree if T2 is equal or inherited from T.  A constraint that you do not check, it will bomb with this exception if it is not the case.  Clearly this question needs a simple repro example to make it crystal.  Since this uses Reflection, there is no point in avoiding declaring *generated* as type T so the compiler will tell you when you get it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each property defined on a type in .NET is different, even if they have the same name. You'd have to do this:

```
foreach (var prop in propertiesForGenerated) 
{
    var otherProp = typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name);
    var valFirst = otherProp.GetValue(manuallyCreated, null) as IComparable;
    var valSecond = prop.GetValue(generated, null) as IComparable;

    ...
```

Of course this doesn't take into account that some properties defined on `T` may not exist on `T2`, and vice versa.

Comment: Beat me to it. Unfortunately, I have the suspicion that this method of reflection might be kind of slow. I think reflection tends to be a bit more optimal if you can retrieve `Type`s, `PropertyInfo`s, and other reflection objects beforehand and only once.

Answer (score 0):

Because `manuallyCreated` is not of type `T2`. Try getting the property object with the same name on that type, and it should work (or if your assumption that all properties in T2 are also in T1, you'll get a better error):

```
public static bool SameCompare<T, T2>(T manuallyCreated, T2 generated){
    var propertiesForGenerated = typeof(T2).GetProperties();
    int compareValue = 0;

    foreach (var prop in propertiesForGenerated) {
        var firstProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name);
        var valFirst = firstProperty.GetValue(manuallyCreated, null) as IComparable;
        var valSecond = prop.GetValue(generated, null) as IComparable;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be better to have Interface of the properties you need to compare,
I would then inherit `IEqualityComparer<YourInterface>`

and in Equals and GetHashCode

```
public bool Equals(YourInterface one, YourInterface two)
{
    return this.GetHashCode(one) == this.GetHashCode(two);
}

public int GetHashCode(YourInterface  test)
{
    if(test == null)
    {

      return 0;
    }

     int hash = 0;
     //// get hash or set int on each property.

     return hash;
 }
```